# What does the down arrow on a policy icon mean in the Group Policy Editor?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have seen this in many places throughout the Group Policy editor and I don't know what it means:

[image: Group Policy Editor]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrow means that it isn't actually a Policy setting, but a preference.

It is not stored in the registry where the other policy settings are, and if the policy would be refreshed, this setting would remain.

See also, the note on this particular (and other similar) policies, which you can see if you go to the Extended tab instead of the Standard tab. Its the last note on the description.

The note says:
Note: This registry setting is not stored in the Policy key and thus is considered a preference. Therefor if the Group Policy Object that implements this setting is ever removed, this registry setting will remain.

Comment: This particular screenshot is a grab from the Internet, so I couldn't read the description.  I've just seen it with myriad other policies before and I finally got annoyed enough to ask about it.  That being said, that behavior is expected for preferences but not for policies. Why is it not in the preferences area of Group Policy then? Also is there some documentation for those icons? I've seen others too that I've always been curious about.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't work for Microsoft. I don't know why its not in the description and is in the extended view. I guess its in the extended view because its there where the icon is visible too. I don't know of any other icons. Or maybe I do, but I don't know which icons you refer to. I once was curious about this too and a colleague told me. That's how I know.

Comment: @WesSayeed In the future please submit your own screenshots when asking a question

Comment: @Ramhound; Why?

Comment: Because in this case you didn't read the description of the policy, which contained the explanation, for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

the arrow means this is a preference and is basically set once. If the GPO binding is removed from the object, the settings will persist. By using the extended tab and viewing the policy explanation this is mentioned in the lower part

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).